# Не работает flex выравнивание с top и left

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, safari

Добрый день, появилась вот такая проблема, добавила все возможные префиксы, проверила написание, и пробовала конфигурации flex, но кроссбраузерно не получается выровнять блоки. Конкретно проблемы с Safari (5, для примера), Chrome (45, для примера).

Что получаю:
[image: Реальность]
Что хочу получить:
[image: Ожидание]
Если кто-то подскажет в чем ошибка, буду очень благодарна.

```css
#adtc_bike_data {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: red;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.row.header-row {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a5d5f2;
}

.bike-row {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.bike-row .col,
.bike-row .col {
  padding: 13px 9px;
}

.bike-name,
.bike-max-qty {
  border-right: 2px solid #a5d5f2;
}

.bike-row .col span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="adtc_bike_data">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row header-row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 bike-name-header"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bike-max-qty-header"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bike-row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 bike-name col"><span>F 800 GS</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bike-max-qty col"><span>4</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col">
        <div class="input-number-box">
          <input type="number" data-bike_price="0" name="adtc_bike_selection[1124]" value="0" min="0" max="4" price="0" style="display: none;">
          <input class="input-number" type="text" value="0" min="0" max="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox и Safari **5**??? Очень похоже на то, что указанные версии просто не поддерживают flexbox даже с префиксами

Comment: Хотя, если судить по [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) в частности для пятого сафари поддержка была, во-первых, частичная, во-вторых, для старой спецификации. Поэтому в этой версии браузера все может работать абсолютно по другому

Answer (score 1):

`flex-box` тут не при чем. Вы пытаетесь выровнять `span` по вертикали внутри блока. Вы указываете `display: flex;` для контейнера `.bike-row`, его дочерние элементы - блоки `.col`, именно на них и будет распространяться `flex-box` выравнивание. `.col span` в этом не принимает никакого участия.

Далее, `span` - это `inline` элемент (если вы не указываете другой `display` явно). Чтобы выровнять его по вертикали, нужен как минимум еще один `inline` элемент, тогда вы сможете выровнять их по вертикали друг относительно друга. Чтобы это выравнивание было по всей высоте контейнера, один элемент должен быть высотой с этот контейнер. Этот второй элемент может выглядеть, например, так:

```css
.aligner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

В итоге, реализация в вашем случае может выглядеть так

```css
#adtc_bike_data {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: red;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.row.header-row {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a5d5f2;
}

.bike-row {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.bike-row .col {
  padding: 13px 9px;
}

.bike-row .col span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bike-name,
.bike-max-qty {
  border-right: 2px solid #a5d5f2;
}

.aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="adtc_bike_data">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row header-row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 bike-name-header"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bike-max-qty-header"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bike-row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 bike-name col"><div class="aligner"></div><span>F 800 GS</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bike-max-qty col"><div class="aligner"></div><span>4</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col">
        <div class="input-number-box">
          <input type="number" data-bike_price="0" name="adtc_bike_selection[1124]" value="0" min="0" max="4" price="0" style="display: none;">
          <input class="input-number" type="text" value="0" min="0" max="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```